# Errors when compiling Apache ORC on macOS 10.15.6

Tags: c++, macos, clang, orc

I'm compiling Apache ORC on my macOS Catalina 10.15.6 (with Apple clang version version 12.0.0 (clang-1200.0.32.2)), Here are some errors. May I ask what caused them?

```
(base) karlkatzen@chloes build % make package testout
[  6%] Built target protobuf_ep
[ 11%] Built target lz4_ep
[ 17%] Built target libhdfspp_ep
[ 23%] Built target googletest_ep
[ 28%] Built target snappy_ep
[ 34%] Built target zstd_ep
[ 39%] Built target zlib_ep
[ 39%] Building CXX object c++/src/CMakeFiles/orc.dir/io/InputStream.cc.o
In file included from /Users/karlkatzen/Documents/code/orc/c++/src/io/InputStream.cc:20:
In file included from /Users/karlkatzen/Documents/code/orc/c++/src/io/InputStream.hh:22:
/Users/karlkatzen/Documents/code/orc/c++/src/Adaptor.hh:177:9: error: keyword is
      hidden by macro definition [-Werror,-Wkeyword-macro]
#define constexpr const
    ^
In file included from /Users/karlkatzen/Documents/code/orc/c++/src/io/InputStream.cc:20:
In file included from /Users/karlkatzen/Documents/code/orc/c++/src/io/InputStream.hh:23:
In file included from /Users/karlkatzen/Documents/code/orc/c++/include/orc/OrcFile.hh:25:
In file included from /Users/karlkatzen/Documents/code/orc/c++/include/orc/Reader.hh:22:
In file included from /Users/karlkatzen/Documents/code/orc/c++/include/orc/BloomFilter.hh:25:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/vector:274:
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/__bit_reference:145:49: error: 
      cannot specify any part of a return type in the declaration of a
      conversion function; put the complete type after 'operator'
    _LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY _LIBCPP_CONSTEXPR operator bool() const _NOEXCEPT
                                            ^~~~~~~~
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/__bit_reference:152:5: error: 
      constructor cannot have a return type
    _LIBCPP_CONSTEXPR
    ^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/__config:887:29: note: 
  expanded from macro '_LIBCPP_CONSTEXPR'
#  define _LIBCPP_CONSTEXPR constexpr
                        ^
/Users/karlkatzen/Documents/code/orc/c++/src/Adaptor.hh:177:19: note: expanded
  from macro 'constexpr'
#define constexpr const
              ^
In file included from /Users/karlkatzen/Documents/code/orc/c++/src/io/InputStream.cc:20:
In file included from /Users/karlkatzen/Documents/code/orc/c++/src/io/InputStream.hh:23:
In file included from /Users/karlkatzen/Documents/code/orc/c++/include/orc/OrcFile.hh:25:
In file included from /Users/karlkatzen/Documents/code/orc/c++/include/orc/Reader.hh:23:
In file included from /Users/karlkatzen/Documents/code/orc/c++/include/orc/Common.hh:22:
In file included from /Users/karlkatzen/Documents/code/orc/c++/include/orc/Vector.hh:32:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/iostream:37:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/ios:215:
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/__locale:208:31: error: 
  constructor cannot have a return type
    _LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY _LIBCPP_CONSTEXPR id() :__id_(0) {}
```

P.S. Here is how I ran cmake: `cmake -DOPENSSL_ROOT_DIR=/usr/local/opt/openssl -DOPENSSL_LIBRARIES=/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib ..`

Comment: The root of the problem is the source code uses marco which's is a C++ keyword name which is a warning, also a constructor of a class has return type, which is syntax error.

Comment: What is the exact version of Apache ORC? Have you modified the source code?

Answer (score 0):

`_LIBCPP_CONSTEXPR`  is LibCxx standard library compiler definitions.
Your orc library code's definitions was conflict with compiler definitions, so in this file `/Users/karlkatzen/Documents/code/orc/c++/src/Adaptor.hh:177:9: error: keyword is hidden by macro definition [-Werror,-Wkeyword-macro]  #define constexpr const` 
just comment this line `#define constexpr const`.